# Overwrite param in Nginx args

Tags: nginx

For the path `/{any string with one or more char}/foo`, I need to overwrite the param `id`. It may be there, it may not be. I want to keep the other params.

Examples:

1. `/a/foo` -> `/a/foo?id=$id`
2. `/bar/foo?id=99` -> `/bar/foo?id=$id`
3. `/123/foo?id` -> `/123/foo?id=$id`
4. `/bar/foo?id=99&id2=100` -> `/bar/foo?id=$id&id2=100`

What I tried:

```
  location ~* ^/.+/foo/*$ {
    if ($args ~ (.*)(id.*)(.*)) {
      return 302 $uri?$1$3;
    }

    set $url $uri?${args}&id=$id;
    return 302 $url; 
  }
```

However, the param is not getting replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` block will not extract the leading and trailing arguments correctly as you need to identify the `&` separators.

Try:

```
location ~* ^/.+/foo/?$ {
    if ($args ~ ^(.*&)?id[^&]*(&.*)?$) {
        return 302 $uri?$1id=$id$2;
    }
    return 302 $uri?id=$id$args; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's hitting the location. I added `return 302 google.com;` right above `location` and `/bar/foo?id=99` didn't go there. Would `location ~* /foo$` actually match it? Because I require there to be at least one char `/{here}/foo`, that's why I had the `^/.+/`. Also `/*$` means it can end with zero or one `/`, so it should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, your right, the regex is fine. If the `location` is not being selected to process the requested URI, you should expand your question to show the complete `server` block.